# Hide Ribbon Tab Headers in the FluentRibbon Suite Controls for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, fluent-ribbon

I'm using the [Fluent Ribbon Control Suite](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon/), to develop an application, and i would like to be able to use the ribbon control using one single tab and hidin the tab selection area.

Here there are some picture to show what i want to achieve.

[image: Starting Point]

[image: What i want to do]

Comment: You cannot Template the Header of the RibbonTabItem in the fluent Ribbon. Use Microsoft Ribbon control it has got RibbonTab and you can customize it using HeaderTemplate property. If you still want fluent ribbon you might need to check with the fluent https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon/issues

Comment: A perfect answer for hiding the ribbon tab header line could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383515/9758687

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the height and width of `tabitem = 0` to achieve the same

```
<fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="" Height="0" Width="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do, the solution is change

```
[..]
    <RibbonTab Header="Nuovo atleta"> 
[..]
```

into

```
[..]
    <RibbonTab > 
[..]
```

After you must create your own style for the `RibbonTabHeader` here is an example and it will fix it:

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style TargetType="RibbonTabHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RibbonTabHeader">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this helps someone, setting `RibbonTabItem.Height` to `0` and `Ribbon.CanMinimize` to `False` collapses the title bar of Fluent Ribbon.